# What do you call the 'intro document' that new employees get on their first day?

Tags: word-choice

I'm referring to the "master plan document" of how they'll learn all they need to learn in order to start working at company X. Often this is a mega tome of links and sub-links, or lists of lists, sometimes kept in a wiki.

The Hebrew term is תוכנית חפיפות - but the translation of this to English is too horrible to repeat here.

Comment: I'm curious about what "תוכנית חפיפות" translates to that's so horrible. Doesn't it just mean "transition program"?

Comment: [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/#iw|en|%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%97%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA) renders it as "program overlaps" -- ambiguous, but not hideous.

Comment: @MarkBeadles - hideous as in "totally not related to the original meaning of the expression", not as PG-18.

Comment: I still don't understand how that is "horrible". Now I'm *really* curious: What is the translation? :)

Comment: We often call the process of getting a new employee started "onboarding"

Comment: @nohat - right, Google does that too. Why a comment and not an answer?

Comment: @MarkBeadles - "overlap program" or "overlap plan" is the closest direct translation. The origin of the meaning is when a new hire starts working, sometime a senior will work closely together with him (e.g. pair programming), or "overlap" him. I guess it's not really horrible pair say, I just cringe when I hear or think about direct word-to-word translations like that.

Comment: @ripper234 I guess it's not really an answer but a related comment without any kind of source or evidence. The Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onboarding does seem to give the term some credence.

Comment: Pseudo edit: replace "pair say" with "per se" in my last comment. I hate making spelling mistakes in places where I can't edit (like Stack Exchange comments after 5-10 minutes). Especially on **English SE**. In my defense, this was 4AM here after a few days without much sleep.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Companies I have worked at called it an "orientation manual."

Or, you can borrow a concept from the consumer electronics world, and call it a "quick start" document (the "Quick Start Guide to Working at Mossad" for example).

Comment: "orientation manual" sounds good to me. But all I remember getting is "staff handbooks"

Comment: Or "employee handbook".

Comment: Newbies got a separate document, and even went through new employee orientation at a couple of places I've worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is also called an Induction. The documents collectively are usually called Employment policies, individually they would be Holidays Policy, Dress Code policy, Non-Disclosure policy, privacy policy, etc.

Comment: All these sound terribly uninteresting. I was thinking more of things like coding style, 10,000 feet project roadmap, key people to know in the org chart ... things that help you be productive.

Comment: @ripper234 Are you talking about something specific to what programmers might do? You mention "coding style" and "project roadmap".  Our answers are more about employees in general.

Comment: @MarkBeadles - The context of my question is indeed software development, but I would imagine the same practices are held in a lot other fields. You know, beyond all the beuarocracy, a new hire has to learn a core set of company-specific "things" in order to function on his first day.

Comment: "induction document".  Induction means you start working there; it's more than just the document.