# Specific verb for "training an apprentice"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, synonyms

Does a specific verb exist for the process of passing on information or skills including the passing of responsibilities between an experienced worker and a new one? The verb *train* is too general, as it applies to any time frame during a job, not necessary during the beginning of one's employment. Moreover it does not include passing of responsibilities.

There exists a slang term for this verb in Hebrew (loosely transliterated as "overlap"), and I'm looking for its English equivalent.

Comment: [_Apprentice_](http://www.onelook.com/?w=apprentice&ls=a) can be used as a verb as well as a noun. Could that work, perhaps?

Comment: I'm looking for the verb that describes the "trainer's" actions, not the the apprentice's. A noun describing the "training" would be fine too.

Comment: @J.R. The verb *apprentice* means “To bind as an apprentice; to indenture.” I don’t think it works here for what the OP seems to want.  OED citations: § 1769 Burke *Pres. St. Nat. Wks.* II. 109 ― When they are apprenticed, this provision will cease.  §1882 Blades Caxton 5 ― In 1438 Caxton was apprenticed to Robert Large.

Comment: @tchrist: I don't think it works, either, which is why I didn't include it in my answer. But I thought the comment he left as an answer to my question was a helpful clarification.

Comment: This sounded *so* familiar. It's actually a duplicate! http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58885/what-do-you-call-the-intro-document-that-new-employees-get-on-their-first-day In that question, the answer was "orientation".

Comment: @MarkBeadles: Wow! With the Hebrew and everything...

Comment: @J.R. It was the Hebrew part that tickled my memory

Comment: It's anecdotal but everybody used the term "ramp up" at Microsoft. The senior "ramped up" the new hire. The new hire was "getting ramped up".

Comment: @MarkBeadles: Your link seems like a totally different question to me! This question is asking about transferring detailed technical information to another employee (not necessarily one that is new-to-the-company, just new-to-the-area).  The linked question is about orienting a new-to-the-company person: where is the bathroom? how do I book my vacation days? etc. Nothing to do with the specific area of knowledge.

Comment: @PeterK. - This actually is the same Hebrew term used, but (apparently) different companies use the term differently :)

Comment: @nbubis: Interesting! Sorry, I can't read Hebrew (except through Google translate.. which gives me "program overlaps" --- which sounds more like this question than the question it's in!). To me "program" is more technical than operational / HR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When this has happened in my professional experience, [we always called it "transfer of knowledge" or "knowledge transfer".](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_transfer)

This certainly doesn't get the sense of transferring the responsibility, but that is implied: the person receiving the knowledge would be the "go to" person for that area of work.

Answer (score 29):

Does "[mentor](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mentor)" fit the bill?

> v. men·tored, men·tor·ing, men·tors Informal
>       v.intr.
>           To serve as a trusted counselor or teacher, especially in occupational settings.
>       v.tr.
>           To serve as a trusted counselor or teacher to (another person).

Comment: Mentor is close, but it does not encompass the passing-on of responsibilities.

Answer (score 15):

I can't think of a word, but there is this idiom: **show the ropes**.

The [Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/show+the+ropes) says:

> **show somebody the ropes**
>   to explain to someone how to do a job or activity : *The new secretary started today so I spent most of the morning showing her the ropes.*

Comment: That's just a brief process, a crash course… an apprentice is more like a protege.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I agree – it's not a perfect match, but it was the best I could think of to get the ball rolling. I think it's one of those answers that, though perhaps not a 100% match, still deserves a mention in the conversation.

Answer (score 7):

There is a verb but it's not commonly used, [*induct*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/induct#English):

> to formally or ceremoniously install in an office, position, etcetera.
>   to introduce into (particularly if certain knowledge or experience is required, such as ritual adulthood or cults).
>   to draft into military service.
>   to bring in as a member.

It's more commonly used as a noun, [*induction*](http://www.admin.cam.ac.uk/offices/hr/staff/new/probation.html):

> The induction you will receive in your local department/institution will enable you to:
>
> - Meet your key colleagues.
> - Find your way around your workplace.
> - Understand your terms and conditions of employment.
> - Understand your role, key responsibilities and how you fit into your department/institution.

An *induction* meets one of your requirements as it is almost always done at the start of someone's employment, however it does not imply any hand-over of responsibilities, only that of giving an understanding to a new employee.

Comment: 'induction' is to formally make part of an organization, and may not involve any actual training or instruction. Some may be 'inducted' into a Hall of Fame, for example. It certainly doesn't involve training them, and may not even involve showing them the washrooms.

Comment: @DJClayworth I disagree, as the basic elements of behavior/pattern that are presented during induction are often more the 'secrets' and 'oral tradition' than *techniques* conveyed for doing a work / job.  Being inducted is synonymous with oral traditions and the traditions and guilds for which one typically is an apprentice.

Comment: Have to disagree with you there. Induction is ["*formal* installation in an office, benefice, or the like"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/induction?s=t). Some companies use it to mean initial basic training, but it doesn't have to be that and it would be the wrong word to use if you *specifically* wanted to mean training. I think the questioner is asking about more in-depth training than this anyway.

Answer (score 7):

English has the verb "apprentice".   In my experience, this is most commonly used in the *intransitive* form:

> to serve as an apprentice    ("She apprenticed with Bob in her youth.")

However, there is also a *transitive* counterpart:

> to set at work as an apprentice; especially : to bind to an apprenticeship by contract or indenture  ("Why Paul Revere's father apprenticed him instead of sending him to college.")

Perhaps that fits more what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Definition of **[initiate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/initiate)**:

> 1. to cause or facilitate the beginning of : set going
> 2. to induct into membership by or as if by special rites
> 3. **to instruct in the rudiments or principles of something : introduce**

Answer (score 4):

How about [groom](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/groom), as in "groomed for success" or "grooming her replacement"?

> Definition of GROOM
>
> transitive verb 3 : to get into readiness for a specific objective :
>   prepare "was being groomed as a presidential candidate"

Answer (score 3):

[Cross-training](http://management.about.com/cs/people/a/crosstrain.htm) or orienting (from orientation) are both used for the passing on of knowledge and duties to another employee:

> From dictionary.com:
>
> "**orientation**" -  3. an introduction, as to guide one in adjusting to new surroundings, employment, activity, or the like: New employees receive two days of
>   orientation.

Comment: I probably should have thought this one through first; +1, even if "orientation" does not involve "passing of resposibilities", nor "cross-training" does that.

Comment: "orientation" really only refers to the most basic of knowledge passing. "orientation" frequently doesn't tell you anything about doing your job - just information you need before you start doing your job.

Answer (score 3):

A common idiom used in the industry is **to bring him/her up to speed** ([See link](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bring+something+up+to+speed)).

- It is your responsibility to mentor the freshers and bring them up to speed.

Answer (score 2):

*[Break in](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/break_in#Verb)* (“To cause (something, or someone, new) to function more naturally through use or wear” or “To tame; make obedient; to train to follow orders of the owner”) sometimes is used; *ie*, to “break in a new hand” means to show a new employee the ropes and how things are done.

The previously-mentioned verb *[initiate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/initiate#Verb)* (“To instruct in the rudiments or principles; to introduce”) is another possibility, as is *[shakedown](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shakedown#Noun)*, a noun referring to a trial or test period.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider [*understudy*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/understudy):

> *v.tr.*
>
> 1. To study or know (a role) so as to be able to replace the regular performer when required.
> 2. To act as an understudy to.
>
> *v.intr.*
>
> To be engaged in studying a role so as to be able to replace the regular performer when required.

Originally a theater term, an understudy (in the noun form) is the backup to the regular performer who is a more experienced/better performer. The understudy *studies under* the regular performer - a sort of apprentice for that role. The regular performer, at one time, was most likely an understudy to someone else so understudy may also be thought of as a rite of passage, of sorts.

Outside of theater, understudy, in my experience, retains the connotation of taking over when the teacher is not able to perform his/her duties (and therefore may not be the best word in all contexts).

Answer (score 0):

How about "takeover"? American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition:

> n. The act or an instance of assuming control or management of or responsibility for something ...

Comment: Sounds a bit violent to me, but "takeover of responsibilities" comes close I guess.

Comment: I think _takeover_ is usually used at the corporate level, as in [this news article](http://www.digitaltrends.com/web/netflix-shares-soar-on-rumors-of-microsoft-takeover/).

Comment: I think you're looking for "cutover", from classic IT forms. However I don't think "apprentice" includes "assuming control"...

Answer (score 0):

A meaning of the word "[probation](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/probation?__utma=1.237409200.1354040328.1355058485.1355058516.20&__utmb=1.41.9.1355059057814&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1354796776.14.4.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=%28organic%29%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=%28not%20provided%29&__utmv=-&__utmk=102263681)" is:

> the testing or trial of a person's conduct, character, qualifications, or the like.

Some jobs have "probationary periods" wherein employees receive their training. This could be used as a noun describing the training process: "the trainee's *probation*." During probation, a trainer "[initiates](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/initiate?s=t)" a new worker. From dictionary.com:

> initiate (verb): introduce into the knowledge of some art or subject.

A person could be initiated into the specifics of sausage casing or masonic chants. In either case, a trainer takes an active role in passing along information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a specific word for this. Why would you need one? "Train" is fine. You just need to say "He trained his apprentice in...", and the entire meaning is conveyed. Training is just one of the things that an apprentice is entitled to, and apprenticeship is as much about the duties as the entitlements of the apprentice.

I suspect that the reason there isn't a special word for it is that it wouldn't add anything. So much is implied by the notion of apprenticeship that once this context is known, ordinary words like 'train' can be interpreted correctly.

Comment: Perhaps it's a cultural difference. In organizations where people leave frequently and moreover are not very organized, knowledge and responsibility are frequently lost - hence the importance of passing on both in an orderly fashion.

Comment: I don't see any cultural difference. Of course passing on knowledge is important, which is why there are apprenticeship systems. It's just that there's no need for a special word for training when the trainee is an apprentice.

Answer (score 0):

A single word is not in use in English to describe this, to my knowledge.

What a master does is *teach the trade/craft* i.e. performs an educational service at the end of which the apprentice is considered to have assimilated the body of knowledge the master himself possesses.